# Datasets in Chart.js stacked barchart appear overlaid instead of stacked

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a stacked barchart using 2 datasets with Chart.js but I find they overlay instead of stack. Is this because of the known bug with a time series for the x-axis or have I done something wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chart.js test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div style="width:90%;margin:20px auto">

  <canvas id="myChart" width="90%"></canvas>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["6 Mar","7 Mar","8 Mar","9 Mar","10 Mar","11 Mar","12 Mar","13 Mar","14 Mar","15 Mar","16 Mar","17 Mar","18 Mar","19 Mar","20 Mar","21 Mar","22 Mar","23 Mar","24 Mar","25 Mar","26 Mar","27 Mar","28 Mar","29 Mar","30 Mar","31 Mar","1 Apr","2 Apr","3 Apr","4 Apr","5 Apr","6 Apr","7 Apr","8 Apr","9 Apr","10 Apr","11 Apr","12 Apr","13 Apr","14 Apr","15 Apr","16 Apr","17 Apr","18 Apr","19 Apr","20 Apr","21 Apr","22 Apr","23 Apr","24 Apr","25 Apr","26 Apr","27 Apr","28 Apr","29 Apr","30 Apr","1 May","2 May","3 May","4 May","5 May","6 May","7 May","8 May","9 May","10 May","11 May","12 May","13 May"],
            datasets: [
            {
                        label: 'dataset1',
                        data: [163,43,67,48,61,74,0,342,342,0,403,407,676,63,1294,1035,665,967,1427,1452,2129,2885,2546,2433,2619,3009,4324,4244,4450,3735,5903,3802,3634,5491,4344,8681,5233,5288,4342,5252,4603,4617,5599,5525,5850,4676,4301,4451,4583,5386,4913,4463,4309,3996,4076,6032,6201,4806,4339,3985,4406,6111,5614,4649,3896,3923,3877,3403,3242],
                        backgroundColor:'rgb(0,102,204,0.8)'
                    },{
                        label: 'dataset2',
                        data: [1,1,0,1,4,0,2,1,18,15,22,16,34,43,36,56,35,74,149,186,183,284,294,214,374,382,670,652,714,760,644,568,1038,1034,1103,1152,839,686,744,1044,842,1029,935,1115,498,559,1172,837,727,1005,843,420,338,909,795,674,739,621,315,288,693,649,539,626,346,268,210,627,494],
                        backgroundColor:'rgb(204,0,102,1)'
                    }           ]
        },
        options: {
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 10
                }
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  stacked: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 20,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    minRotation: 0,
                    major: {
                      fontStyle: 'bold',
                      fontColor: '#FF0000'
                    }
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    stacked: true,
                    labelString: 'Number'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }]
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Chart title'
            },
            responsive: true
        }
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickwuk/va280yn7/32/)

Hopefully the above jsfiddle explains the issue pictorially. The barchart shows daily data for two datasets which are supposed to be stacked, but dataset1 overlays dataset2 and therefore obscures dataset2 unless transparency is set for dataset1, and then the colour is not correct because it's a combination of one colour over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply define your `yAxes` as stacked also as shown below.

```
yAxes: [{
  stacked: true,
```

> Also try to use the latest stable version of Chart.js (currently v2.9.3)

Please have a look at your amended code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chart.js test</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div style="width:90%;margin:20px auto">

  <canvas id="myChart" width="90%"></canvas>

  <script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["6 Mar","7 Mar","8 Mar","9 Mar","10 Mar","11 Mar","12 Mar","13 Mar","14 Mar","15 Mar","16 Mar","17 Mar","18 Mar","19 Mar","20 Mar","21 Mar","22 Mar","23 Mar","24 Mar","25 Mar","26 Mar","27 Mar","28 Mar","29 Mar","30 Mar","31 Mar","1 Apr","2 Apr","3 Apr","4 Apr","5 Apr","6 Apr","7 Apr","8 Apr","9 Apr","10 Apr","11 Apr","12 Apr","13 Apr","14 Apr","15 Apr","16 Apr","17 Apr","18 Apr","19 Apr","20 Apr","21 Apr","22 Apr","23 Apr","24 Apr","25 Apr","26 Apr","27 Apr","28 Apr","29 Apr","30 Apr","1 May","2 May","3 May","4 May","5 May","6 May","7 May","8 May","9 May","10 May","11 May","12 May","13 May"],
            datasets: [
            {
                        label: 'dataset1',
                        data: [163,43,67,48,61,74,0,342,342,0,403,407,676,63,1294,1035,665,967,1427,1452,2129,2885,2546,2433,2619,3009,4324,4244,4450,3735,5903,3802,3634,5491,4344,8681,5233,5288,4342,5252,4603,4617,5599,5525,5850,4676,4301,4451,4583,5386,4913,4463,4309,3996,4076,6032,6201,4806,4339,3985,4406,6111,5614,4649,3896,3923,3877,3403,3242],
                        backgroundColor:'rgb(0,102,204,0.8)'
                    },{
                        label: 'dataset2',
                        data: [1,1,0,1,4,0,2,1,18,15,22,16,34,43,36,56,35,74,149,186,183,284,294,214,374,382,670,652,714,760,644,568,1038,1034,1103,1152,839,686,744,1044,842,1029,935,1115,498,559,1172,837,727,1005,843,420,338,909,795,674,739,621,315,288,693,649,539,626,346,268,210,627,494],
                        backgroundColor:'rgb(204,0,102,1)'
                    }           ]
        },
        options: {
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 10,
                    right: 10,
                    top: 10,
                    bottom: 10
                }
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  stacked: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 20,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    minRotation: 0,
                    major: {
                      fontStyle: 'bold',
                      fontColor: '#FF0000'
                    }
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  stacked: true,
                  scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    stacked: true,
                    labelString: 'Number'
                  },
                  ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }]
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Chart title'
            },
            responsive: true
        }
    });
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had included the stacked parameter ... but in the wrong place! I should have seen that, thanks.